# Difference between pandas DataFrames by certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to identify a subset of rows from one `DataFrame` that are not present in another `DataFrame`, when compared by only a few columns.

For example,

```
df1 = DataFrame([dict(id1=1, id2='ABC', val=23.45), dict(id1=2, id2='MNO', val=21.23)])
df2 = DataFrame([dict(id1=1, id2='ABC', val=42.45)])

# pseudo code
diff_df = df1 - df2  # compare only by id1 & id2, as a pair
>>> diff_df
   id1  id2    val
1    2  MNO  21.23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example :

```
df1[~ (df1.id1.isin(df2.id1) & df1.id2.isin(df2.id2))]

   id1  id2    val
1    2  MNO  21.23
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a few steps to get there, so it's probably possible to optimize this a bit:

```
matches = df1[['id1', 'id2']].drop_duplicates().isin(df2[['id1', 'id2']])
not_present = ~ matches.all(axis=1)
df1.ix[not_present]
Out[16]: 
   id1  id2    val
1    2  MNO  21.23
```